# Background fetch working in simulator but not working in real device

Tags: ios, swift5, background-task, xcode11.1

I am calling API to get data and show local push based on the response of API so I am using `background fetch` service of Apple which is introduce in `iOS 13` and above.

But when try to test this scenario in simulator and it works fine but when I checked this app in real device then it is not working and lost the connection when it tries to call api in background.

I am not killing my app from device just put back by click on home button.

I am not sure why it is not running in real device.

What I did till now. Steps are here:

1. I have enable background fetch from capabilities of app project.
2. then I have added this code in `AppDelegate`

   ```
   extension AppDelegate {

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

     print("Bg Fetch from App Delegate 1")

     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {

     BroadCastManager.sharedInstance.fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: completionHandler)

   }
   }
   }
   ```
3. This will call one method from service class where one API will be call and then based on response api it will fire one local push.

So here problem is that when API is call in real device and app is in background then i am getting below error.

error screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @CodeBender that isn't applicable to the background task APIs.

Comment: Please edit your question to show relevant code.

Comment: @Paulw11 Edited question and write some code & steps to get it with details.

Comment: That isn't the new api, that is the old api. Why do you dispatch after 3 seconds instead of just doing the work?

Comment: 3 seconds of delay is not an issue sir. It is just delay for push. If i do without it then also it is not working in device. As i mention in above question, it is working in simulator but not working in real device. @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is iOS12 and earlier.  Try the new process.  I just gave an example (my app's working code) here:

[BGAppRefreshTask Background Task Not Executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138351/bgapprefreshtask-background-task-not-executing/62163193#62163193)